# Declaration of variables fails in vb.net VS 2015

Tags: vb.net, variables, visual-studio-2015

VB in VS 2015.  This code fails.  Neither the boolean nor the integer have a value when the code halts.  The error message is "BC30451:  is not declared.  It may be inaccessible because...".  Perhaps this is Microsoft's way of telling me I'm an idiot for not coding in C#? Anyone know why this is failing?

```
Shared Sub test()
    Dim N As Boolean = False
    Dim i As Integer = 5
    Stop  ' Neither N nor I are accessible
End Sub
```

[Edit - add code from comment]

```
Private Sub cmdSaveAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave1.Click
    Dim N As Boolean = False 
    Dim i As Integer = 5 
    Dim ss As String = "xxxx" 
    Stop ' Neither N nor I nor ss are accessible 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the Stop keyword.  As for your problem, all I can say is Works on my Machine (VS2015).  Do you have a yellow arrow on Stop when you try to inspect the values?  Try setting a breakpoint on the Stop and seeing what you get.

Comment: Need more information to attempt to answer. You should provide a [minimal **complete** verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ; as-is we can't know what is executed and when ; even your error message seems incomplete.

Comment: I tried to keep it brief, obviously too brief for Sehnsucht.  Lots of code and long descriptions create only confusion for me.  And coding for over 30 years has led to impatience.The complete error is (1) : error BC30451: 'ss' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Rather than rewrite the sub and the call again:

Comment: Private Sub cmdSaveAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave1.Click
  Dim N As Boolean = False
  Dim i As Integer = 5
  Dim ss As String = "xxxx"
  Stop  ' Neither N nor I nor ss are accessible
 End Sub

Comment: Reformatting of sub courtesy of Stack Overflow.  Sorry.

Comment: Do you mean that `the variables aren't accessible` from the outside? Really? Then  you should IMMEDIATELY read about [variable scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx). Or you can't write ANY program.

Comment: Thanks @Frank.  You will notice that the variables are not accessible from *within* the subroutine.  Guess I wasn't clear.

Comment: You aren't even trying to access them.

Answer (score 1):

If you never use a variable, Visual Studio is smart enough not to add it to the stack. The same goes for Subroutines that are never called in a program - they are not added to the executable.

Try this:

```
Shared Sub test()
    Dim N As Boolean = False
    Dim i As Integer = 5
    If N Then
      Console.WriteLine("This line will never be hit.")
    Else
      Console.WriteLine(i)
    End If
End Sub
```

Alternately, you could declare your variables outside of the routine, so that they have scope elsewhere.

```
Private N As Boolean
Private i As Integer

Private Sub cmdSaveAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave1.Click
    N = False 
    i = 5 
End Sub

Shared Sub test()
    If N Then
      Console.WriteLine("This line will be hit if N is changed in another method.")
    Else
      Console.WriteLine(i)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution, but the problem must be in the application under development or a bug in 2015.  I created a new project and this code works just fine.

New Info:  I was in release mode.  Switching to debug fixed the problem.  I have been, however, developing in release mode for quite some time, so I don't know if this is a bug or meant to be and I never encountered the problem before.  Hmmm, most strange.